# How to show that Shift Left Logical multiplies by 2^n?

Tags: assembly, mips

I read that Shift Right Logical divides the number by 2^n and I did the below to prove it.

```
srl $t2,$t1,1

  $t1:  10100111  :  167
  $t2:  01010011  :  83
```

Also, I read that Shift Left Logical multiplies by 2^n. However I can not show this.

```
sll $t2,$t1,1

  $t1:  10100111  :  167
  $t2:  01001110  :  78
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Actually srl is INTEGER DIVISION with 2^n

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to guess that you're operating on 8-bit types, so your left-shifted value overflows.

- (167 * 2) = 334
- 334 % 256 = 78

Comment: So is it true that sll multiplies 2^n ?

Comment: @Kaoukkos Try a number smaller than 167 instead. To be exact, 127 or smaller.

Answer (score 1):

You are throwing a bit away when you shift. The solution is really 101001110, but only 01001110 can be stored (according to the example).

So, normally yes, sll multiplies by n^2, if it fits in the registers.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it does, by definition.  Lets look at base 10.  I take the number 12345.  I left shift that by one position, filling in with zeros I get 123450.  do it again 1234500 and so on .  For each position I multiply by 10.  if I do three shifts then that is 10*10*10 or 10^3.  n shifts left of base b is the same as multiplying by b^n.  base 2, base 8, base 10, base 16.  all works the same.