# Shifting bits left to achieve exponentiation to the power of two Javascript

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following:

```
var n = 3;
```

I want 2^n power.

So I can do:

```
Math.pow(2,n)
```

That equals 8, sweet.

Or I could do:

```
1 << n
```

That also equals 8, sweet.

I am trying to picture the shift of bits.

So I think n's, which equals 3 in this example, binary notation is:

**11**

That is (1 * 2^1) + (1 * 2^0) = 3

So then I do the operation `1 << n` and the bits shift left ONE, I think the output of `1 << n`, in binary notation, is this:

**110**

The bits shift left one position, replacing the first bit with zero BUT this equals 6 not 8:

That is (1 * 2^2) + (1 * 2^1) + (0 * 2^0) = 6

**Not sweet, after the bit shift left I am calculating that `1 << n` would equal six based on my binary notation, `1 << n` does equal 8 so my binary notation of the left bit shift manipulation is incorrect**

Either I am drafting the binary notation of 3 incorrectly and/or I am not shifting the bits left correctly in my binary notation for the output of `1 << n`

Could anyone provide an explanation to where my thought processes are incorrect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show that Shift Left Logical multiplies by 2^n?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212510/how-to-show-that-shift-left-logical-multiplies-by-2n)   --  I realize that the languages are different, but it doesn't really matter at all to this question.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  Not sure what meaningful answer you are looking for.  Should be something you could find more than enough on with a Google search.

Comment: The question is a bit muddled so it's not 100% clear where the confusion is. For one, you say "I want n^2 power" but `Math.pow(2,n)` is 2^n, not n^2. Later you're describing `1 << n` but your calculations are for `n << 1`.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer, I want 2^n and I am calculating 1 << n. Where do you see me calculating n << 1, in my binary notation? I am reading 1<< n as "shift n bits left 1" is this incorrect?

Comment: @jfriend00 what is correct? Something is incorrect in my line of thinking, I am coming up with a binary notation output of n << 1 to be equal 110 but that is incorrect because 110  is 6, so my thinking is wrong.

Comment: Not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212510/how-to-show-that-shift-left-logical-multiplies-by-2n IMO. I could not find resolution to my question with that Stackoverflow question/answer thread

Comment: Well `11` is 3 and `110` is 6 which is `3 * 2`, exactly what one would expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1 << n` means: add `n` zeros at the end of the binary representation of `1`.
That produces `1 * 2ⁿ = 2ⁿ`. In your case, `2³ = 8 = 10002`.

`n << 1` means: add `1` zeros at the end of the binary representation of `n`.
That produces `n * 2¹ = 2*n`. In your case, `2*3 = 6 = 1102`.

Therefore, the problem is that you confused `1 << n` and `n << 1`.